# setting the number of visible rows in a dandelion datatable

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, dandelion

I want a dandelion datatable to show 15 rows at a time instead of the default 10 rows.  Can someone show me how to accomplish this?

Here is some code that I displaying 10 rows at a time with pagination controls to scroll between sets of 10 rows:

```
<datatables:table id="mydata" data="${mydataset}" cdn="true" row="mr" theme="bootstrap2" 
    cssClass="table table-striped" paginate="true" info="false" 
    cssStyle="width: 150px;" align="left" dom="frtp">
    <datatables:column title="Concept Type" cssStyle="width: 150px;" display="html">
        <c:out value="${mr.something}"/>
    </datatables:column>
</datatables:table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lengthChange` attribute  which allows user to select the size of a formatted page from a select menu (`sizes are 10, 25, 50 and 100`)

this property will only work when  `paginate="true"`

**if you don't want to show dropdown and would like change it to 15 then you override below property**

```
global.feature.displayLength=15
```

default value of above property is 10 thatswhy you are its showing 10 result.

please use below code and give a try

```
<datatables:table id="mydata" data="${mydataset}" cdn="true" row="mr" theme="bootstrap2" 
    cssClass="table table-striped" paginate="true"  info="false" 
    cssStyle="width: 150px;" align="left" dom="frtp" lengthChange="true">
    <datatables:column title="Concept Type" cssStyle="width: 150px;" display="html">
        <c:out value="${mr.something}"/>
    </datatables:column>
   <datatables:prop name="feature.displayLength" value="15" />
</datatables:table>
```

**How to Override ??**

- you can add a file called `datatables.properties` at the root of the
  classpath, allowing you to redefine every property you need. Your
  custom global configuration will then be merged with the default one.
- Or you can locally override properties using the `<datatables:prop>` JSP tag. Just define the property's name and
  value.

Comment: +1 and Thank you.  I changed your code to indicate paginate=false, then tried your suggestion.  Since there are only 14 rows in my dataset, I cannot tell whether or not your lengthChange tag did anything in addition to the paginate=false.  But I am marking this as the answer because for my fixed length dataset, it solved the problem of getting everything on one page.

Comment: I am trying to get my dandelion datatable to only populate after the user has entered at least three characters into the search box.  Are you willing to help me with this new question also?  here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662863/speed-up-data-access-in-a-search-form/23663075?noredirect=1#comment36349362_23663075

Comment: New versions are not working I am using dandelion 1.1.1  having problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834638/dandelion-datatables-ajax-url-is-not-working