# Dandelion Datatables AJAX url is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, datatables, dandelion

JSP Code is as below

```
<datatables:table id="studentMeetingtbl" url="getStudentMeetingList"        serverSide="true" processing="true"  
 row="studentMeeting" rowIdBase="id" rowIdPrefix="studentMeeting_" 
 displayLength="10" lengthMenu="10,15,25,50,100"    jqueryUI="true"  
 filterable="true" sortable="true"  
 autoWidth="true" pageable="true" 
 paginationType="full_numbers" 
 stateSave="true" >
<datatables:column title="Id" property="id" filterable="false" sortable="false" searchable="false" visible="false" />
<datatables:column title="Actions" renderFunction="actions" filterable="false" sortable="false" searchable="false" display="HTML" />
<datatables:column title="Id" property="id" />
<datatables:column title="Group Name" property="group.groupName" />
<datatables:column title="Project Name" property="group.projectName" />
<datatables:column title="Meeting Date" property="meetingDate" renderFunction="ParseDateColumn"/>
<datatables:column title="Next Review/Meeting Date" property="nextReviewDate" renderFunction="ParseDateColumn"/>
<datatables:column title="Remarks" property="remakrs" />
</datatables:table>
```

Output is

[image: Output]

Stack trace in browser is 
[image: trace]

As we can see it is not fetching anything from specified `url="getStudentMeetingList"`.

Please show way to resolve this issue. Is this because tomcat 8 or 7 is incompatible with datatables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
  <mvc:resources mapping="/dandelion/**" location="/dandelion/" />
```

in dispatcher it solved pipelining problem.

Comment: *What* pipelining problem? What has this answer got to do with this question? Don't just copy-and-paste answers.